# I want to bundle font awesome css/icons cx js APP

Tags: cxjs

Want to bundle font awesome with dist files .I am creating one cx js app that could install on restricted server verion

Answer (score 1):

This should not be a problem. You should download Font Awesome and place it in the assets folder. Then import all.css from index.scss.